# How do I convert a differential RF signal to a single ended signal?

Tags: rf, wireless, differential

I'm using an RF transceiver that has a differential pair output. I want to route it to an SMA connector. How do I convert the differential signal to a single ended signal?

Comment: Often times you can simply 50 ohm terminate one of the two halves and take the other as a single-ended signal, although obviously you will lose half of the amplitude.

Answer (score 2):

You use a balun this is a transformer which will convert the balanced differential pair output to the unbalanced SMA-coax.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frHfLJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>